# Efficient read/write approach with Java NIO

Tags: java, nio

Let's say we have SocketChannel (in non-blocking mode) that registered with Selector for read interest. Let's say after select() Selector tells us that this channel is ready for read and we have some ByteBuffer. We want to read some bytes from our channel to this buffer (ByteBuffer is cleared before reading). For this we use channel's read() method that returns actual number of bytes read. Lets suppose that this number is positive after read from channel and also ByteBuffer's method  hasRemaining() returns true. Is it practical in this situation to immediately try to read from same channel some more?
The same question for write(). If write() returns positive value and not all contents of the buffer was sent, is it practical to immediately try again until write() returns zero?

Comment: So long as you're in non-blocking, you should read/write until the return value is `<= 0`, meaning either it would block or end-of-stream. By the way, far more often than not, your channel will be write-ready, so you should avoid using write interest as it will make your `select` loop just spin. Only set an interest in write-readiness when `SocketChannel.write` would block before finishing writing the data.

Comment: @veer Yes, i forgot to mention that all this is about non-blocking mode.

Comment: But is it really efficient to try until return value is <= 0? I mean, if last read() returned > 0 but failed to fill our buffer fully, is it really worth to try to read immediately again? Is there a high probability that this next read() will return positive value? Or positive return value and non-fully filled buffer indicates that we (most probably) drained internal socket buffer and should return to selection?

Comment: Uh... I don't think you understand what's going on here. `ByteBuffer.hasRemaining` means you have space left to fill in your buffer. Whether `read` fills your buffer or not is not the same as reading all available data from the socket.

Comment: @veer Yes, it's not the same. But as i suspect, most probable cause for fail to fill buffer fully is that there are currently no more available data to read from socket (and the new data will be available after some "long" time, so we should return to selection). I'm interested to know is it really true in practice. If it is true, we can stop our read loops earlier and do smaller number of read() calls (not wait for <= 0 return value, but break also with positive return values and not fully filled buffers).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you get a short read result, there is no more data to read without blocking, so you must not read again until there is. Otherwise the next read will almost certainly return zero or -1.

If the read fills the buffer, it might make sense from the point of view of that one connection to keep reading until it returns <= 0, but you are stealing cycles from the other channels. You need to consider fairness as well. In general you should probably do one read and keep iterating over the selected keys. If there's more data there the select will tell you next time.

Use big buffers.

This also means that it's wrong to clear the buffer before each read. You should get the data out with a flip/get/compact cycle, then the buffer is ready to read again and you don't risk losing data. This in turn implies that you need a buffer per connection.

Comment: Thanks for answers! Buffer clearing was mentioned only for the sake of example - to clarify about initial state of buffer.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on the data rate at which data is arriving, and the latency requirements of your application.  If you don't care about latency at all, you might get slightly higher bandwidth by delaying your read interest until you suspect enough data has arrived to fill your buffer.

You have to be careful, though.  Delaying reads could force the kernel to buffer more data, possibly fill its buffer, and have to start dropping packets or otherwise engage some flow control.  That will more than kill any benefits from the last paragraph.

So generally, you want to read as much as you can, as early as you can.  The benefits for batching reads are minor at best, and the potential pitfalls can be major.  And keep in mind that the fact that you're seeing non-full reads means you're processing the data faster than it is coming in.  In other words, you're in a state where you have CPU to burn, so the extra overhead of smaller reads is essentially free.

Comment: I don't fully agree with "The benefits for batching reads are minor at best" - Be careful as many small reads imposes a huge burden on mechanical drives. This magnifies when you have multiple users as the drive will be seeking a lot and only reading small chunks of data. Balance between the number of simultaneous requests, memory available, and latency requirements.

Comment: @Joe: first, we're talking about network, not disk.  Even if it was disk, disks (and the OS) have caches, so you wouldn't actually be seeking on each request.